# Store information in a array with a while loop inside function

Tags: php, arrays, function

How can I store information in a array?

I'm trying to get information from a database and then store HTML code in the array.

Is this possible? If so how?

```
function echothatshit() {
    $sqll=mysql_query("select id,data from produkter where weight='1'");
    $alla = array();    
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqll))
    {
        $idd=$row['id'];
        $data=$row['data'];
        $alla[] = '<option value="'.$idd.'">'.$data.'</option>';
    }
}

$test2 = echothatshit();                       
echo $test2;
```

Comment: What exactly do you wish to store, what have you tried, and what didnt make sense?

Comment: Im trying to store a html string. <option value.... etc.

Comment: And what is  not working? You are storing <option value... in array $alla, the only thing You should do is return $alla;

Comment: please dont use mysql functions use PDO or mysqli as mysql has been depricated as noted on the php man page in the big red box http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function echothatshit() {
    $sqll=mysql_query("select id,data from produkter where weight='1'");
    $alla = array();
    $i=0;    
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqll))
    {
        $idd=$row['id'];
        $data=$row['data'];
        $alla[$i] = '<option value="'.$idd.'">'.$data.'</option>';
        $i++;
    }
    $yourVariable="";
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)
    {
        $yourVariable.=$alla[$j];
    }
    return $yourVariable;
}

$test2 = echothatshit();                       
echo $test2;
```

Comment: err... `$i` is never incremented... how this is supposed to work? why that inner loop?

Comment: Well spotted, too much gin, not enough concentration left. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You just need `return $alla;` at last of your function, also you can not echo an array directly, you need to loop it.

Comment: Yes ive tried that but the result from $test2 is only the output "array"

Comment: @oBo Because you need to do `$test2[0];`

Comment: @xdazz please explain the `$test2[0]` in your post, so people should better understand it

Answer (score 1):

Why not having `$alla` as string, that is (with a few formatting / renaming / simplification):

```
function getProductsHTML()
{
  $sql = mysql_query("select id,data from produkter where weight='1'");
  $html = '';

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    $html .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['data'].'</option>'."\n";

  return $html;
}

echo getProductsHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function echothatshit() {
$sqll=mysql_query("select id,data from produkter where weight='1'");
$alla = array();    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqll))
    {
$idd=$row['id'];
$data=$row['data'];
$alla[] = '<option value="'.$idd.'">'.$data.'</option>';
    }
return $alla;
}
$test2 = echothatshit();                       
echo $test2;
```

If you want that $test2 gets array $alla, return that.
And then, in order to print array correctly, use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test2);
echo "</pre>";
```